# How to debug Openfire plugin classpath issue

Tags: debugging, classpath, server

I've written an Openfire (3.8.2) plugin which uses Avaya DMCC API (5.2.3). When I run the code as a plugin (within Openfire server), the Avaya DMCC API method call returns a null value (have ensured I'm supplying valid arguement to method call):

ServiceProvider provider = ServiceProvider.getServiceProvider(spProp);

When I run the code as a stand-alone java application, the call works fine.

I think the problem is classpath related (i.e. different version of some class being loaded by Openfire server which causes method call to return null). I'd appreciate any advice on general debugging of such an issue

Comment: I used Jad and JadClipse within Eclipse to remotely single step though the code which was running on a CentOS box (added -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8002 to the java coomand line that starts up the Openfire server). Single stepping through the code revealed the following:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Jad and JadClipse within Eclipse to remotely single step though the code which was running on a CentOS box (added -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8002 to the java coomand line that starts up the Openfire server). Single stepping through the code revealed the following: I’ve tracked the problem through to the Avaya DMCC API to a piece of code that marshals objects to xml. The Avaya code includes the following 2 jars:

MD5 /cmapijava-sdk/lib/avaya-castor-override.jar) = 2855ac187cb077607b11564adddb24db
MD5 /cmapijava-sdk/lib/castor-1.0-xml.jar) = 58982f4f140ab7c873e629c63e11282d
MD5 /cmapijava-sdk/lib/xerces-J_2.9.1.jar) = 63af2ba098d68df388197f887d548734

There is a class called org.exolab.castor.xm.Marshaller which is in the castor-1.0-xml.jar That is the standard castor Marshaller which uses the xerces-J_2.9.1.jar (). Avaya then actually have their own org.exolab.castor.xm.Marshaller in the avaya-castor-override.jar (along with about 11 other classes they are overriding). They have added an extra method ( setCstaXSDEdition(…) ) which is called as part of code execution. That is the statement that causes errors when doing remote single-stepping through the code.

I’ve concluded that the wrong version of org.exolab.castor.xm.Marshaller (e.g. either the one in castor-1.0-xml.jar or even some other jar which is part of the openfire jars) is being used when code is run as an openfire plugin, as opposed to a stand-alone java app.

I’ve tried adding the avaya-castor-override.jar to the -classpath (at the very beginning of it) of the java openfire launch command, but that made no difference.
I’ve tried adding the avaya-castor-override.jar to the JRE endorsed directory (/usr/java/jre1.7.0_67/lib/endorsed/) but the code falls over much earlier in execution (it obviously uses the avaya-castor-override.jar Marshaller in the wrong place and should have used the normal version found incastor-1.0-xml.jar)

Solution:
Force openfire to it to pick up the right org.exolab.castor.xm.Marshaller from the right jar file.
It turns out that Openfire plugins load classes in alphabetic order.
The order of jars within the build made no difference when running on my IDE (Eclipse) or centos. When I renamed castor-1.0-xml.jar to avaya-**a**castor-1.0-xml.jar (so alphabetically coming before avaya-castor-override.jar), that caused the same error to occur when running on my IDE. Doing the same thing to the centOS version jar made it work on centOS